# gcinfo log generated running a spring-boot application in linux server

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, spring-boot-actuator

Running a spring boot jar on linux machine always gives an error log saying gcinfo with the below output.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_51-b16), built on Jun  8 2015 19:28:07 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
Memory: 4k page, physical 98840040k(29491820k free), swap 12287996k(11747796k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:BaseFootPrintEstimate=2147483648 -XX:+BindGCTaskThreadsToCPUs -XX:InitialHeapSize=2147483648 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=2147483648 -XX:MaxNewSize=805306368 -XX:NewSize=805306368 -XX:OldPLABSize=8192 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-ResizeTLAB -XX:-ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:TLABSize=262144 -XX:ThresholdTolerance=100 -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:YoungPLABSize=262144 
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 688128K, used 4101K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 589824K, 0% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d04014e0,0x00000000f4000000)
  from space 98304K, 0% used [0x00000000fa000000,0x00000000fa000000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 98304K, 0% used [0x00000000f4000000,0x00000000f4000000,0x00000000fa000000)
 ParOldGen       total 1310720K, used 0K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 1310720K, 0% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000080000000,0x00000000d0000000)
 Metaspace       used 6863K, capacity 6902K, committed 7040K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 823K, capacity 847K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K
```

Can see the initial and maximum heap sizes are same in the above log, Is this because of this ?, It stops immediately saying unexepected shutdown hook JVM error. Is it because the other process is taking a lot of memory, Any command that helps in looking at statistics would be useful

Comment: This info is printed because of `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` option. This is not an error.

Comment: @apangin- Thanks for the comment, this is only getting generated when the JVM crashes (May be the logic was written to print out ), This log is printed saying 2021-03-18 12:30:28,988  INFO [Shutdown Hook] - Unexpected JVM shutdown, What could be the possible reason, please suggest

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and the actual problem. Heap info printout is not relevant, as it is always printed on JVM exit, if there is `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` option.